# Javascript prototyping

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

what is the difference between adding a method as a prototype and defining inside the constructor function

For eg: between

```
function Car( model, year, miles ) {
this.model = model;
this.year = year;
this.miles = miles;
this.toString = function () {
         return this.model + " has done " + this.miles + " miles";
};
}
```

and

```
function Car( model, year, miles ) {
this.model = model;
this.year = year;
this.miles = miles;
}

Car.prototype.toString = function () {
        return this.model + " has done " + this.miles + " miles";
};
```

Comment: The first `new Car().toString === new Car().toString; //false`
The second `new Car().toString === new Car().toString; //true`

Comment: Please indent your code.

Answer (score 1):

1. `this.toSting` adds a property to each new object made using the `Car` constructor.
2. `Car.prototype` is a separate object where all objects made using `new Car(...)` inherit properties from. Because `toString` is a property of the prototype object, this is inherited by all `Car` objects.

Let `var car = new Car(...);`

Both are accessed by calling `car.toString()`.

However when the call is made, car is first searched for the `toString` property. If none exists, then the prototype is searched for `toString` and that is called instead. If neither exist, then the prototypes prototype is searched all the way up the chain until `toString` is found on the base objects prototype.

Comment: new car delegates to the prototype. ;-)

Comment: @synthet1c If the inheritance of a property through the prototype chain is conditional on whether or not said property is found on the object, can this still be clarified as delegation? I agree inheritance is not the best term.